# PostgreSQL 200GB database simple query low performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-performance

I've just started working with databases and I am completely new in this area - so please forgive me if the question is silly.

I have to store a huge amount of data from ~4000 sensors. Each one logs readouts every minute. For now I have to store in the db data from three years but with a time it will grow.

The database will have around 200 GB and now it has 150 GB. I wanted to get all data for the sensor with id 1 and between the specific dates (for example 
'2017-12-06' and '2017-12-07').

```
select * 
from raw_sensor_data 
where idSensor=1 
  and time> DATE '2017-12-06' 
  and time < date '2017-12-06' + interval '1 day';
```

The problem is that the query takes much longer than I've expected. How can I improve the performance of this DB? Maybe the design of the db is wrong? The db is currently stored on a HDD drive.

```
CREATE DOMAIN T AS double precision; 

CREATE TABLE Sensors(
    id smallserial PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    position    T   NOT NULL,
    name    text    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE raw_sensor_data(
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    time    timestamp NOT NULL,
    readout T   NOT NULL,
    idSensor    smallint references Sensors(id) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the tables? Specifically on `idsensor` and `time`?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't know that I have to add extra indexes. I turn on indexing and as soon as it finishes I will check performance of my db.

Comment: Worth reading: http://use-the-index-luke.com/